# How do I scrape all links in a webpage? My code only scrapes some of the links

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my code to scrape all links in a webpage:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

page = requests.get("http://www3.asiainsurancereview.com/News")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
    print(link.get('href'))

links.close()
```

But it lists out only the links that are present in the drop downs. Why is that? Why did it not "see" the links of the news articles present in the page? I actually want to scrape all the news articles. I tried the following, to identify a tag and scrape the news article links within that tag:

```
import requests
import re

links=open("Life_and_health_links.txt", "a")
page = requests.get("http://www3.asiainsurancereview.com/News")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

li_box = soup.select('div.col-sm-5 > ul > li > h5 > a')
for link in li_box:
    print(link['href'])
```

But this, of course, displays only the links in that particular tag. And to list out links in other tags, I have to run this code multiple time specifying the specific tag whose link I want to list out. But, how do I list out all the links of the news articles in all the tags, and skip the links that are not of news articles?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some research to find the common pattern for news links.

Try this, hope it works.

```
li_box = soup.select("div ul li h5 a")
for a in li_box:
    print(a['href'])
```